# Get PID from bash command

Tags: php, bash, ffmpeg, pid

Hi i have bash command to run ffmpeg continously from PHP script, how can i get PID from ffmpeg process that run inside bash command. because i want to stop ffmpeg process and the bash command for specific PID, currently i already get PID from bash command and stop all ffmpeg process with `pkill ffmpeg`.

Any suggestions please.

Thanks

Here is my code

```
public function playCam($ip)
{
    $dataPlay = array();
    $randomFolder = rand(5, 15);
    $vidDir = '/var/www/cctv/public/video/'.$randomFolder.'/';
    exec('mkdir '.$vidDir);
    $bash_commands = '
    while :
    do
    ffmpeg -y -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:FIW170845@'.$ip.':554/stream=2.sdp -vf scale=854:480 -r 3/1 -t 120 '.$vidDir.'ip-%01d.jpeg
    done';
    $pid = exec($bash_commands.' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!; ', $output);
    $dataPlay = [0 => $pid, 1 => $randomFolder];
    return $dataPlay;
}

public function stopCam($pid,$folder)
{
    shell_exec('kill '.$pid);
    shell_exec('pkill ffmpeg');
    $vidDir = "/var/www/cctv/public/video/".$folder.'/';
    $del = File::deleteDirectory($vidDir);
    return 'stoped';
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one-liner:

```
for result in $(pgrep -a ffmpeg); do if [ "$(echo "$result" | grep "IP_TO_CHECK_FOR")" ]; then pkill $(echo "$result" | cut -d " " -f1); fi; done
```

first you'll get all information on all processes of ffmpeg. then, you'll check each of which for the IP (modify the pattern if the IP itself is not sufficient for checking) and kill the PID of the particular process by extracting it via `cut` (the PID is the first part of the output before a blank " "). Since `grep` also supports regular expressions, you might need to unmask the dots in your IP via \.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i already try it using pgrep -f ffmpeg and it show only pid from ffmpeg process , but how to get pid for specific ffmpeg process that contain specific ip address ? for example i have 2 running ffmpeg process: ffmpeg -y -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:FIW170845@10.11.121.122:554/stream=2.sdp -vf scale=854:480 -r 3/1 -t 120 /path/ip-%01d.jpeg and ffmpeg -y -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:FIW170845@10.11.121.124:554/stream=2.sdp -vf scale=854:480 -r 3/1 -t 120 /path/ip-%01d.jpeg , how to get pid from ffmpeg with ip adress 10.11.121.124 ?

Comment: oh ok, I see. please have a look at my updated answer, @Kamikaze. In my first one, I put the focus not on your PHP-code but to the shell-command itself and therefore I misunderstood the part about checking the IP. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You already output the PID of your last backgrounded process, which is ffmpeg, with `echo $!` (see [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_0024_0021)).  It should show up in `$output`, but you don't fetch it from there currently.